# How to force a conversion of string to int in a linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am getting the error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Before my question gets called as a duplicate please read it completely. I have searched around and looked at a few solutions for this but none that seems to suit this..

```
var query = from royalHIstory in ctx.tblRoyalHistories
    join historyComment in ctx.tblRoyalHistoryComments
    on royalHIstory.RoyalHistoryID equals historyComment.RoyalHistoryID
    orderby royalHIstory.IndexNum ascending
    where royalHIstory.InstNmbr == instnmbr
    select new
    {
        RoyalHistoryID = royalHIstory.RoyalHistoryID,
        RoyalHistoryCommentID = historyComment.RoyalHistoryCommentID,
        InstNmbr = royalHIstory.InstNmbr,
        IndexNum = royalHIstory.IndexNum,
        RoyalIns = royalHIstory.RoyalIns,
        RoyalComment = historyComment.Comment,
        Name = (from memberName in ctx.tblMembers
               join instruct in ctx.tblInstructors
               on memberName.MemberID equals instruct.MemberID
               where Convert.ToInt32(instruct.InstructorInstrNo) == royalHIstory.RoyalIns
               select memberName.MemberFirstName + " " + memberName.MemberLastName).FirstOrDefault()
    };
```

The error lands on my where clause, in the conversion

> where Convert.ToInt32(instruct.InstructorInstrNo) == royalHIstory.RoyalIns

I need that conversion to happen

> Convert.ToInt32(instruct.InstructorInstrNo)

and I don't know how to force it to happen

Comment: In LINQ To Entities - no way. Try the opposite `instruct.InstructorInstrNo == royalHIstory.RoyalIns.ToString()` which is supported.

Comment: I hope you can still adjust you data model. If two fields hold similar data (which they do when you are comparing them!) it makes absolutely no sense that their data types should be different. If the data model is fixed, try to kick whoever made it so.

Comment: Why do you think that this is not a duplicate? The problem is still the same, you are using a NET Framework method that cannot be translated in some kind of Sql (In this case Convert.ToInt32)

Comment: @IvanStoev, i tried that earlier, but the query was missing a record, when I checked the SQL that this query generates it casts the royalHIstory.RoyalIns as a varchar, which is expected, and its always misses the first record based on the id which is only 3 characters long. So in the SQL script if I cast the instruct.InstructInstrNo as an int and leave the cast on the royalHIstory.RoyalIns as a varchar then I get the correct records without missing the MemberFirst and LastName

Comment: @oerkelens, the tblInstructor.InstructorInstrNo is a string, the RoyalHistory.RoyalIns is an int

Comment: @Steve, I don't believe its a duplicate, even though the problem is the same, the solution is not

Comment: It's simple. L2E does *not* support conversion *from* string - no CLR method, no canonical function. No solution.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I understand that. But if you are comparing them, they should have the same data type in your data model. It makes no sense at all that one of them is a `string` if it has to be compared to an `int`. So `tblInstructor.InstructorInstrNo` should be an int.

Comment: @oerkelens, yes you would think that tblInstructor.InstructorNo should be an int, but whoever designed this table wasn't thinking to much about that.

Comment: Hence my remark about changing it, or trying to make that person think about those things in the future.

Comment: @oerkelens, I think I got it figured out, its gonna be another question though...How to put an If Else statement in the where clause

Answer (score 0):

you can't use

```
Convert.ToInt32(instruct.InstructorInstrNo)
```

in LINQ query, if you want to convert to int try this

```
var query = (from royalHIstory in ctx.tblRoyalHistories
join historyComment in ctx.tblRoyalHistoryComments
on royalHIstory.RoyalHistoryID equals historyComment.RoyalHistoryID
orderby royalHIstory.IndexNum ascending
where royalHIstory.InstNmbr == instnmbr
select new {royalHIstory,historyComment }).AsEnumerable().Select(row=>new
{
    RoyalHistoryID = row.royalHIstory.RoyalHistoryID,
    RoyalHistoryCommentID = row.historyComment.RoyalHistoryCommentID,
    InstNmbr = row.royalHIstory.InstNmbr,
    IndexNum = row.royalHIstory.IndexNum,
    RoyalIns = row.royalHIstory.RoyalIns,
    RoyalComment = row.historyComment.Comment,
    Name = (from memberName in ctx.tblMembers
           join instruct in ctx.tblInstructors
           on memberName.MemberID equals instruct.MemberID
           where Convert.ToInt32(instruct.InstructorInstrNo) == row.royalHIstory.RoyalIns
           select memberName.MemberFirstName + " " + memberName.MemberLastName).FirstOrDefault()
});
```

Comment: getting does not exist for the variables in the select new statement

Comment: It is not clear....Please explain more. but it works true and the result would be what you want.